# Select LIKE not working on XAMPP with MariaDB

Tags: php, sql, xampp, mariadb, sql-like

I cannot get "LIKE %M" to work on XAMPP with MariaDB.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE names LIKE 'm%' ORDER by names ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in selecting " . 

mysqli_error($connection));


$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($emparray);
```

this returns a blank screen, no errors or anything.

but if i switch to something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE names = 'SomeName' ORDER by names ASC";
```

it runs just fine, so I know its not a problem connecting to the DB.
And I have researched through this site for the answer first, so I am pretty confident that my code is correct.

just not sure if this is a problem with XAMPP and/or MariaDB, or if I just missed something stupid.

Thanks in advance, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: No names start with "m".

Comment: if there is no errors it means there is no records starts with 'm'

Comment: Also there is a huge difference between '%M' and 'm%'

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have many that start with M... for example if put the name Mike in there, it returns just fine

Comment: question's unclear and as per an answer given. Representive values and schema should have been included.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out....

one of my names had an umlaut over the O (Ö).

I didn't realize it was there, but once I noticed it and removed it.. it worked just fine.